# Confusing Tautological 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential

I have read about this related question,
[Tautological 1-form on the cotangent bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252180/tautological-1-form-on-the-cotangent-bundle)
and have asked some professor and is still being confused.

So let $M=\mathbb{R^2}$, $N=\mathbb{R}$.
$F:M\rightarrow N$ by $F(x_1,x_2)=x_1\in N$.
Given $\alpha(y)=\xi(y)d y\in C^\infty(N; T^*N)$, we can pull it back as
$$(F^*\alpha)(x_1,x_2)=\xi(x_1)d x_1,$$
which we can thinking of it as a field of arrow on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane pointing in the $x_1$ direction with its norm independent of $x_2$.

Now SUDDENLY, let's make $M\equiv T^*N= T^*\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2$ (therefore $F$ can also be called $\pi$), so $\xi$, as $\alpha(\partial_{x_1})$, is actually $x_2$. But to distinguish it from the coordinate, let's call it $\hat{x_2}$:
$$F^*\alpha(x_1,x_2)=\xi(x_1)d x_1=\hat{x_2}(x_1)d x_1,$$
$\xi(x_1)$ or $\hat{x_2}(x_1)$ is still a function of $x_1$ (actually, a function of the 2-dimensional coordinate $(x_1,x_2)$, but no dependence on $x_2$). We define
$$\theta=F^*\alpha\equiv \xi(x_1)d x_1$$
Can anybody tell me why the simplectic form on $T^*N=T^*\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2$ can be defined by the following way:
$$\omega=d \theta=d\xi\wedge d x_1\equiv d x_2\wedge dx_1,$$
rather than $d \theta=\partial_{x_1}\xi(x_1)d x_1\wedge d x_1=0$? I haven been stuck on this problem for several days (not that that's the only thing I have been doing), really appreciate it if anyone can help me!

Comment: The canonical one-form is *not* a pullback of a form from the base. Indeed, $\xi$ is the fiber coordinate, not a function of $x_1$.

Comment: $\theta$ is the canonical $1$-form; it is *not* a pullback. Indeed, $\theta = \xi\,dx_1$ and $\omega = d\theta = d\xi\wedge dx_1$. I have no idea where you got your pullback or $\xi = \partial_{x_1}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Hi, for example in <https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/252198/edit>
$\pi^* : T^*_x M \to T^*_{(x, \xi)} (T^* M)$ (same as the notes I am reading).  So I guess I am confusing somethings.  Could you give a clear description on this, am point out why I am wrong in my question?  Thanks!

Comment: That's not even a final post, so I'm not going to look at it. This is talking about projection from the cotangent bundle of the cotangent bundle to the cotangent bundle. You are not.

Comment: (Sorry grab the wrong link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252180/tautological-1-form-on-the-cotangent-bundle)Hi,  I think I am talking exactly about that.  My $M$ is actually $T^*N$; $F$ is actually $\pi$ because it is projecting out the $x_2$, which is actually the "$\xi$" dimension. So in the language of that post, $\theta=\pi^*\alpha$.